# How do I make a serialization class for this?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have something like this (sorry for the bad names)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <root xmlns="http://www.domain.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.domain.com Schema.xsd">
      <product></product>
      <SomeHighLevelElement>
         <anotherElment>
              <lowestElement> </lowestElement>
         </anotherElment>
      </SomeHighLevelElement>
    </root>
```

I have something like this for my class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        ListWrapper= new List<UserInfo>();
    }


    public string product{ get; set; }


    public List<SomeHighLevelElement> ListWrapper{ get; set; }


}

public class SomeHighLevelElement
{

    public string lowestElement{ get; set; }
}
```

But I don't know how to write the code for the "anotherElement" not sure if I have to make another wrapper around it.

**Edit**

I know get a error in my actual xml file. I have this in my  tag

```
xmlns="http://www.domain.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.Domain.com Schema.xsd
```

Throws an exception on the root line saying there was a error with this stuff. So I don't know if it is mad at the schemaLocation since I am using local host right now or what.

Error

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  Message="There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."
  Source="System.Xml"
```

Comment: Post the actual XML, not just an excerpt you think might be relevant.

Comment: Ok I updated the XML that I originally with the lines I thought where crashing as that is the line it crashes on. It just says error Xml 2,2.

Comment: If that's really your XML, then it's malformed; the `xsi:schemaLocation` is missing a closing quote (and it also has a space, which normally shouldn't be there).

Comment: The quote was just a copy and paste error but I corrected the extra space.  I still think it is a pathing error. Like I ran my xml through a validator and the only thing that comes up is The Document `Schema.xsd` could not load! So do I change the location for now to a local host path?

Comment: In visual studios it comes up with this "The schema referenced from this location in your document contains errors." Yet it does not tell me what is wrong with it and when I validate my schema with some online tools it says it is valid.

Comment: @chobo2: Then you might want to post the actual error message you get during deserialization instead of "there was a error with this stuff."  Not to sound flippant, but people can't help you without specifics.

Comment: Sorry it was in one of these comments(2nd comment)

System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  Message="There is an error in XML document (2, 2)."
  Source="System.Xml"

Comment: OK, better, that message is telling you that the error is on line 2, position 2 of the XML document.  Now you'll probably want to check the `InnerException` of that `InvalidOperationException` to see what it's really complaining about.

Comment: I figured it out. It seems that in my serialization class in the XMLRoot I have to specify the namespace in that otherwise it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example based on the info you provided. Basically, you will need to make a separate class for `anotherElment` which contains a `string`.

You can control exactly how your class parses the Xml elements using [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28VS.80%29.aspx), which basically maps your class properties to elements/attributes in the Xml file. So for example, since your document element in the sample Xml you provided is `root`, I explicitly define that `MyClass` has a document element called `root` to match your Xml.  By default, the serializer will look for an element called `MyClass`, and if you omit it, the deserialize method will throw.

This should help get you going:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("root")]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public string product { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SomeHighLevelElement")]
    public List<SomeHighLevelElement> ListWrapper { get; set; }

}

public class SomeHighLevelElement
{
    public AnotherElment anotherElment { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherElment
{
    public string lowestElement { get; set; }
}
```

And a sample test method based on the Xml you provided:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
.
.
.
public void Test()
{
    string xml = @"<root>
                  <product>product name</product>
                  <SomeHighLevelElement>
                    <anotherElment>
                      <lowestElement>foo</lowestElement>
                    </anotherElment>
                  </SomeHighLevelElement>
                  <SomeHighLevelElement>
                    <anotherElment>
                      <lowestElement>bar</lowestElement>
                    </anotherElment>
                  </SomeHighLevelElement>
                  <SomeHighLevelElement>
                    <anotherElment>
                      <lowestElement>baz</lowestElement>
                    </anotherElment>
                  </SomeHighLevelElement>
                </root>";
    MyClass c = Deserialize<MyClass>(xml);
}

public T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
}
```

Comment: Ah I was close with my current version. However I now getting a error in my xml document. I will post what I have in my original post.

Comment: One more thing how do I make it validate. Like for instance I removed my product tag from a xml document I was importing. I expected it to throw an exception but it went on it's merry way. If it is missing I want it to throw an exception. How can I do that.